# How do I change the default Virtual Directory name during a web service install?

Tags: c#, web-services, deployment

I have a C# web service, created using VS2008.

I have a deployment project that creates the MSI I use for deployment.

Is there a setting somewhere to change the default virtual directory that the user is prompted with during the installation?

I'd prefer to not change the name of the webservice to do this.

Answer (score 22):

But isn´t this a simple case of right-clicking the setup project:

select `View`-> `File System`.

From the **File system explorer**, click the `Web Application Folder`. Press `F4` to bring up the properties window (if it isn´t already visible).

In the properties window, scroll down to `VirtualDirectory` and change it to whatever you want.

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the fix.

I couldn't find a fix thru the VS UI, so you'll need to locate your deployment project (file extention is .vdproj) and open in notepad.

Search for "VirtualDirectory"

You'll find a line similar to this:

"VirtualDirectory" = "8:OldName"

Where OldName is the current default you're seeing during installation.

Change "OldName" to whatever you want for a default. Save and build.

If there's a way to do this thru the UI, that would be even better, I couldn't find it and this works.

Comment: This worked for me. Using Visual Studio 2013 there was no Virtual Directory property in the properties of the project. Changing the value in notepad accomplished my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015. The virtual directory can be changed on the properties for the Web.ApplicationFolder for web applications