# msiexec - How do I specify a blank TARGETVDIR?

Tags: command-line, msbuild, windows-installer

We recently upgraded one of our applications from .net 2.0 to .net 3.5 and we have run into an issue with the installer. Essentially the msi auto populates the Virtual Directory field when we want it to be blank. This wouldn't be such an issue except that I cannot figure out how to set the virtual directory blank from the command line.

Currently I have

```
msiexec /i $(InstallerPath)\AppInstaller.msi /qn TARGETVDIR=
```

And I get the error
`The folder path 'CURRENTDIRECTORY="C:' contains an invalid character.`

`.` produces `The folder path '.' contains an invalid character`

Quotes do not work at all.

What can I do to specify a blank Virtual Directory?

**EDIT**

Using [How do I change the default Virtual Directory name during a web service install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860573/how-do-i-change-the-default-virtual-directory-name-during-a-web-service-install)
I tried to manually set it blank in the installer project. However, it is already blank!

Comment: Does it executes from MSBuild `Exec` task? single quotes should work `<Exec Command='msiexec /i $(InstallerPath)\AppInstaller.msi /qn TARGETDIR=""' />`

Comment: I end up with a TARGETVDIR field with quotes in it.

Comment: Why not fix the installer source? if you don't have the source you can use `orca.exe`

Comment: The following link helped me to resolve the issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9766b2ef-b743-4a0a-b73b-576dd505e7c4/setting-targetvdir-to-empty-at-command-line?forum=winformssetup.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro Thanks! For this project I eventually switched to a file copy deployment as the installers were taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck into the same question... I've used space to achieve it and it worked.

Example:

```
> WebSetup1.msi TARGETAPPPOOL="Test" TARGETSITE="/LM/W3SVC/2" TARGETVDIR=" "
```

[image: Installer UI]